# Find and Replace multiple texts from file a in file b

Tags: perl, replace, find

I have a csv file which has on column A (chinese phrases) and on column B (their english equivalents).

On another .xml file I have large amounts of chinese texts. I want to make the script to search from csv file and if found replace the terms on xml file.

The closest that I got to my aim is this code.

```
use Cwd;
use File::Basename;
use File::Copy;
use strict;
use warnings;


my $DIR = $0;
my $filename = basename($0);
$DIR = '/Users/moody/Desktop/chinese/';
#my $tablecounter = 0;
my @GLOSSARY;
my $glossaryFile = 'Chinese.csv';
my $glossaryCount = 1;
my $RAWFILE = "Chinese.xml";
my @MODDEDFILES = ('Chinese-modded.html');

BuildGlossary();

my $FILETEXT = "";
my @MODDED_FILETEXT = ('','','','','','','','','');
ReadRaw($RAWFILE);

my $k = 1;
while ($k < $glossaryCount) {
  my $search = $GLOSSARY[$k][0];
  my $replace = $GLOSSARY[$k][1];
  $FILETEXT =~ s/$search/$replace/g;
  $k += 1;
}
$FILETEXT =~ s/<p><\/p>/<\/br>/g;

PrintText($MODDEDFILES[0]);
SplitText();
$k = 1;
while ($k < 3) {
  PrintTextModded($MODDEDFILES[$k], $k);
  $k += 1;
}

exit;



sub PrintText {
  my $filename = $_[0];
  open(my $fh, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
    or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
  print $fh "<html><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" /><head><style>body {background-color: #bfbfbf; margin-right: 20%; margin-left: 20%;} p {margin: 0px; text-indent: 1.5em; word-wrap: break-word;} h3 {margin: 0px; text-align: center;} hr {border-color:black;}</style></head><body>\n\n";
  print $fh $FILETEXT;
  print $fh "</body></html>\n";
  close $fh;
}

sub SplitText {
  my @temp = split(/(<p>------------------------------------<\/p>)/, $FILETEXT);
  shift @temp;
  my $tempSize = @temp;
  for (my $i=1; $i <= $tempSize; $i+=4) {
    $temp[$i] =~ s/<p>/<h3>/g;
    $temp[$i] =~ s/<\/p>/<\/h3>/g;
  }
  for (my $i=0; $i <= $tempSize; $i+=2) {
    $temp[$i] = "<hr noshade>\n";
  }

  my @volumes = ([0,111],[112,224]);
  for (my $k=0; $k < 2; $k++) {
    my $temptext = "";
    my $i = int($volumes[$k][0]);
    my $u = $volumes[$k][1];
    for (my $j=$i; $j <= $u; $j++) {
      $temptext = $temptext.$temp[$j];
      #$temp[$j] = "";
    }
    $MODDED_FILETEXT[$k] = $temptext;
  }
}

sub PrintTextModded {
  my $filename = $_[0];
  my $num = $_[1];
  open(my $fh, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
    or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
  print $fh "<html><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" /><head><style>body {background-color: #bfbfbf; margin-right: 20%; margin-left: 20%;} p {margin: 0px; text-indent: 1.5em; word-wrap: break-word;} h3 {margin: 0px; text-align: center;} hr {border-color:black;}</style></head><body>\n\n";

  print $fh $MODDED_FILETEXT[$num-1];
  print $fh "</body></html>\n";
  close $fh;
}


sub ReadRaw {
  my $filename = $_[0];
  open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
    or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
  $FILETEXT = "";
  while (my $row = <$fh>) {
    chomp $row;
    $FILETEXT = $FILETEXT."<p>".$row."</p>\n";
  }
  close $fh;
}

sub BuildGlossary {
  open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $glossaryFile)
    or die "Could not open file '$glossaryFile' $!";
  my $num = 1;
  while (my $row = <$fh>) {
    chomp $row;
    my @temp = split "," , $row;
    $GLOSSARY[$num][0] = $temp[0];
    $GLOSSARY[$num][1] = $temp[1];
    $num += 1;
    $glossaryCount += 1;
  }
  close $fh;
}
```

However, the problem is that it still doesn't work. The problems that I face at the moment are:

```
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at find.pl line 74.
Use of uninitialized value $filename in open at find.pl line 85.
Use of uninitialized value $filename in concatenation (.) or string at find.pl line 85.
Could not open file '' No such file or directory at find.pl line 85.
```

Is there anyone who could help me out?

Comment: Please read [mcve].

Comment: Don't give up. Please try to solve first. Error says `No such file or directory at find.pl line 85`, means its unable to open that file for writing (refer to line 85). It would have created file by itself as its opened in write mode, but if you are writing file in a directory, you have to create that directory first.

Comment: Your first error appears at line 74. But if I count lines from the top, line 74 is just the comment:  `#$temp[$j] = "";` . What is exactly line 74 in your code?

Comment: Also provide a small sample of the XML file

Comment: Håkon & Kamal, thanks for reply the problem is solved. The issue was with $DIR = '/Users/moody/Desktop/chinese/';

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with $DIR = '/Users/moody/Desktop/chinese/';
It had to be changed to $DIR =~ s/$FILENAME//g;